# I need to capture the data above one the cell that contains "20DV" in the excel with python using pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I'm using the below code to get the data under destination column of the output file.
In my source file, I have 20DV at multiple places, but my code is give output from only first available 20DV

I tried with the below code

for col in range(1, len(df.columns)):

```
    if df.iloc[0, col] == '20DV':
        destination = df.columns[col]
```

this code is extracting only the data above the first available 20DV, but in my file there many 20DV and the data above is not taking as destination.

Comment: if statement with a pandas dataframe is a red flag usually indicating that there is a better buildin method.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
destination=df.loc[df['col']== '20DV']
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But i did not get the required output